# C#, Extract data from SQL based on search criteria given in a form

Tags: c#, sql, search

I have following combo boxes bound with data from a sql table.

- cmbClassification
- cmbAuthor
- cmbPublisher
- cmbType

I need to extract data based on selected values in these combo boxes.

For example: If I left `cmbClassification` blank and select values for other 3 combo boxes, my datagridview should show all the data for specific author, specific publisher & specific type regardless of the classification.

I know how to do this for two searching items (using if). but i have 4 items and no idea.

### Code for two instances

I think there are 10 search patterns for these 4 combo boxes. how can i handle this? If there are only 2 combo boxes there will be 3 patterns which i will handle as follows:

```
string con = @"Data Source=ABU_DHABI-1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SLIS;Integrated Security=True";


private void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbAuth.Text == "" && cmbClassi.Text =="")
    {
        SqlConnection Icon = new SqlConnection(con);
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM Books";
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Icon);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        BrDataGrid.DataSource = dt;
    }

    if (cmbAuth.Text == "" && cmbClassi.Text != "")
    {

        SqlConnection Icon = new SqlConnection(con);
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Classification ='" + cmbClassi.Text + "'"; ;
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Icon);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        BrDataGrid.DataSource = dt;

    }

    if (cmbAuth.Text != "" && cmbClassi.Text == "")
    {

        SqlConnection Icon = new SqlConnection(con);
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Author ='" + cmbAuth.Text + "'"; ;
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Icon);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        BrDataGrid.DataSource = dt;

    }
}
```

Comment: Using more `if`s. If you want a more useful response, show your current code.

Comment: So you write 4 `if` statements instead of `2`.  Are you asking how to write an `if` statement?  How to use a database?  Something else that's too broad or would be covered by any tutorial?

Comment: I know the db and if. I only don't know how to use the if for this instance. I can write the if statement if there are only 2 search items. can you give a clue please?

Comment: If you show some more detail about how you query the database, we might be able to help you. Without knowing that, there are too many possibilities.

Comment: I update it with code. check  from "-----Code for two instances------" to down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic:

```
if (cmbAuth.Text == "" && cmbClassi.Text != "")
{
    // build and execute the entire query
}
```

would lead to an *exponential* increase in the number of `if` blocks and a *ton* of repeated code.  Which, of course, is bad.

Instead, build the query once with a linear increase in the number of filters applied.  Something logically more like this:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE 1 = 1";
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbAuth.Text))
{
    query = query + " AND Author = @Author";
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Author", cmbAuth.Text));
}
// repeat for each input
// then build and execute the connection/command objects from the query and parameters
```

Basically you build up the query with each condition, then execute the result.  As a bonus, this is also using query parameters rather than the current SQL-injectable code you have.  You can further add slight improvements to this, such as using a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings or perhaps using more explicit SQL data types when building the parameter objects, etc.

This would be similar to a commonly used approach in LINQ, where one might have something like this:

```
var books = db.Books;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbAuth.Text))
    books = books.Where(b => b.Author == cmbAuth.Text);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbClassi.Text))
    books = books.Where(b => b.Classification == cmbClassi.Text);
// etc.
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your time. Thanks.